# Converting datetime to z format

Tags: c#, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C#, given a DateTime object, how do I get a ISO 8601 date in string format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114983/in-c-given-a-datetime-object-how-do-i-get-a-iso-8601-date-in-string-format)

I've a variable with type DateTime in my C# code.
How do I convert this to ["Z" format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/833143/30018)?

Thanks.

Comment: Please link to what `Z format` looks like. What have you tried? What are you stuck on?

Comment: I have to vote this question down.  The author needs to give MORE details about the problem they are having, they need to explain ANY term they use, assume we know nothing.

Comment: your description requires anyone trying to help to google search to understand your question.  This is something you should do yourself and clarify for the people trying to help you.

Comment: I assume [Where's the DateTime 'Z' format specifier?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/833102/704402) covers most of what you are looking to do.

Comment: @deltree: Although I didn't have to google to answer I will admit I have no idea if I've answered the right question. ;-)

Comment: @All,apologies for keeping the question not clear enough.Will keep this in mind while posting questions next time.

Comment: I found this question by googling "z", so I disagree with the earlier comments.  At least the duplicate question helped me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do you mean converting to a string time/date like `2009-06-15 20:45:30Z`? If so then try:

```
mydate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("u");
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx for info on Standard Date and Time format strings. In particular read the entry on using the "`Universal Sortable ("u") Format Specifier`" whcih explains why I have the `ToUniversalTime` call in there.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean the universal sortable date/time pattern:

```
string formatted = theDate.ToString("u");
```

Example result:

```
2009-06-15 20:45:30Z
```

Comment: What a coincidence that we both used the exact same date and time for our example? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Based on [a quick search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) it *seems* to me that you simply mean UTC time, in which case you can use the [`ToUniversalTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime.aspx) method of [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx), and when displaying as a string append "Z" to the end, or use the [Universal Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#UniversalSortable) when calling `ToString`, or you could construct it using a number of format specifiers in the correct order.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your format is ISO 8601:    DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")

Maybe a duplicate of this topic: [Given a DateTime object, how do I get an ISO 8601 date in string format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114983/in-c-given-a-datetime-object-how-do-i-get-a-iso-8601-date-in-string-format)