# Parsing an ISO string in UTC to DateTimeKind.UTC

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Let's say, I have a string like this - "2014-09-30T20:38:18.280", how can I parse this into a DateTime field of DateTimeKind.Utc.

When I perform DateTime.Parse("2014-09-30T20:38:18.280"), it returns the date time in DateTimeKind.Unspecified. When I try to call ToUniversalTime() on that, it shifts the time adjusting UTC offset.

I basically want "2014-09-30T20:38:18.280" itself represented in UTC

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# datetime parse issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787368/c-sharp-datetime-parse-issue)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specify [`DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91hfhz89(v=vs.110).aspx) when you parse.

> If no time zone is specified in the parsed string, the string is assumed to denote a UTC.

I'd also use `DateTime.ParseExact` and specify the invariant culture:

```
var time = DateTime.ParseExact(text, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff",
                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                               DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
```