# C# DateTime.Parse giving strange output

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I have some unit test code failing from colleagues from FR.  I suspect the issue is related to some datetime formats but I'm not sure what the source is.  I have a variable `dt` that doesn't parse the way I think it should.  Below is some output from my Immediate Window

```
dt
"2016-12-14T00:00:00Z"
DateTime.Parse(dt, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{12/13/2016 7:00:00 PM}
    Date: {12/13/2016 12:00:00 AM}
    Day: 13
    DayOfWeek: Tuesday
    DayOfYear: 348
    Hour: 19
    Kind: Local
    Millisecond: 0
    Minute: 0
    Month: 12
    Second: 0
    Ticks: 636172524000000000
    TimeOfDay: {19:00:00}
    Year: 2016
```

`dt` has the value that I think it should, looks to be Dec 14 2016 at midnight.  But when I parse it I get Dec 13 at 7 PM.  Which I find confusing.

Comment: The string is UTC while the verbose report is local time

Comment: Specify a DateTimeStyle with AdjustToUniversal and it'll do what you expected. Or use my Noda Time project instead and there'll be fewer surprises ;)

Comment: Use `Parse().ToUniversalTime()`.

Comment: Look at this very similar [SO Question & Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787368/c-sharp-datetime-parse-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833102/wheres-the-datetime-z-format-specifier)

When "Z" (Zulu) is tacked on the end of a time, it indicates that that time is UTC.

- use DateTimeOffset.Parse(string).UtcDateTime.