# Getting TimeZone from string containing DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I have a DateTime string `"2014-10-09T07:01:39Z"`. I want to get the timezone from this string.

Comment: Does that string appear to contain a timezone?

Comment: Your string doesn't have _any_ timezone information. So, that's not possible.

Comment: Then what is the 'Z' at the end of the string.?

Comment: @Ish How can we know that? This is your string. It might be an offset?

Comment: Regarding [Z](http://stackoverflow.com/a/833143/1997232).

Comment: Z means UTC. So your timezone is UTC.

Answer (score -1):

"2014-10-09T07:01:39Z" means 10/9/2014 7:01:39 AM +00:00

"2014-10-09T07:01:39"  means 10/9/2014 7:01:39 AM +/-LocalTimeZone

```
var dof=DateTimeOffset.Parse("2014-10-09T07:01:39Z");
Console.WriteLine(dof.Offset);
//00:00:00

dof = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2014-10-09T07:01:39");
Console.WriteLine(dof.Offset);
//XX:00:00
```