# Transformation failed BizTalk

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I have a map with a C# script in *Script* functoid to convert a date in dd/MM/yyyy format to yyyy-MM-dd format:

Here is the script I use in my functoid :

```
public string CheckDate(string inputDate)
{
  if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(inputDate))
    return "";
  else
  {
    System.DateTime dt = System.Convert.ToDateTime(inputDate);
    return dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
  }
}
```

For an unknow reason this script works perfectly when I do a *Test Map* in VS, it also works on my DEV environment but when I deploy it on UAT I got this error message:

> General Exception : Error encountered while executing the transform
> XXX. Error:Transformation failed..

I already tried to use `TryParse()` or `TryParseExact()` but the mapping behavior is still the same. Work on DEV and Test Mapping but not on UAT.

### EDIT

I catched the InnerException from Error:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
at System.Convert.ToDateTime(String value)
at System.Xml.Xsl.CompiledQuery.Script1.ConvertCompletedDate(String param)

So the issue is the input value but  I only desn't work on UAT environment. This error is not thrown on DEV. I checked the .NET framework used and they are the same on both environment.

Can someone tells me how I can transform 18/11/2021 to a valid DateTime format ?

Comment: And what is the value of inputDate?   Have you checked the date/time settings on the UAT servers vs DEV.  You might want to use the ToDateTime(String, IFormatProvider) overload to make sure that it is using the format you expect

Comment: Also try putting a try/catch around it and output the inputDate as is in the catch block to help with debugging.

Comment: InputDate value: 17/11/2021, I already log it for debugging purpose.
The code I use in this scripting functoid is already in use on other mapping that are working fine on UAT so it's not an setting issue.
I already tried ToDateTime(String, IFormatProvider), same error.
The try/catch give no more information about the error.

Comment: Are you sure it's failing on that functoid? The error message doesn't make that clear.

Comment: I tested by removing the functoid and the transform works without it.

Comment: The idea behind the try catch is then to write the date to the output field as is, maybe you aren't getting the value you expect.

Comment: Also, please use the [edit] link to add details to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out that my `TryParseExact()` wasn't good.

If you have these kind of error and the issue concern a DateTime, the answer is the @Shar1er80 's reply [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177467/converting-string-to-valid-datetime)