# Invalid Date in Fullcalendar js and Firefox, how to?

Tags: javascript, php, date, fullcalendar, momentjs

I am using php to send some data to fullcalendar, but the calendar dates display as `Invalid Date` or `NaN`

see the date formatting below, any ideas how to fix this?

**PHP**

```
foreach ($dates as $key => $date) {
    //$date->getDate() is a timestamp
    $start = new DateTime($date->getDate());
    $end   = new DateTime($date->getDate() + 1800);

    $array[$key]['start']       = $start->format('c');
    $array[$key]['end']         = $end->format('c');
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$calendar.fullCalendar({
    header     : h,
    defaultView: 'month',
    slotMinutes: 15,
    editable   : false,
    droppable  : false,
    events     : {
        url : '/api',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data
    }
});
```

edit:

I end up using:

```
$dA = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date->getDate());
$datetimeA = new DateTime($dA);

$array[$key]['start'] = $datetimeA->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the date is formatted incorrectly, Firefox require the UTC format to work, which is:

```
 yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd + 'T' + hh + ':' + min + 'Z';
```

behing yyyy the year formatted at 4 digits,
mm the month formatted at 2 digits (January - 00, the zero is important),
dd the day formatted at 2 digits,
hh the hour formatted at 2 digits and
min the minutes formatted at 2 digits.

T and Z are constants.

so just change your format to this if you want with hours and minutes:

```
$array[$key]['start']       = $start->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
$array[$key]['end']         = $end->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
```

hope this works.
Do tell me if it doesn't and we will try to solve it :)

Comment: actually i see that fullcalendar sends `Invalid date` on FF rather then the current date..

Comment: `Z` isn't actually a constant, but rather an indicator of **Z**ulu (UTC) timezone -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833102/wheres-the-datetime-z-format-specifier