# Convert date time in C# while assign to table column

Tags: java, c#, datetime

having problem in converting datetime as required format like bellow

```
string a = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
```

I can get output like  :`2016-03-06T14:23:00.000+08:`

but when I assign to that sting a to some date time value like below

```
DateTime dateform= convert.todatetime(a);
```

I got the output like :`03/23/2016 12:00 P.M`

for dateform object in C# code

actually I have a java service that service expecting "2016-03-06T14:23:00.000+08:" type of datetime but i am unble to send the format from C# code

```
service.aptdate=dateform;//here service.aptdate is datetime type so need to pass as it datetime only
```

when I see the java code they use like

```
XMLGregorianCalendar x=null;
GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

c.setTime(new Date());
xCalUploadedDate = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(c);
```

after he get the required format like "2016-03-06T14:23:00.000+08" but in C# I can't get. Any help how I convert.

Comment: I don't think your `a` will be `2016-03-06T14:23:00.000+08` since you don't have any `f` format specifier and `zzz` should return also minutes part of the current timezone UTC Offset.

Comment: Are you using json to pass data to your java api?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833102/wheres-the-datetime-z-format-specifier This post may help you

Comment: Sorry but your question is not consistent. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: hi, Soner Gönül  thanks for reply here is my problem i need to send the date time to java webservice like (2016-03-06T14:23:00.000+08:)this format.Form java client code he send that format using XMLGregorianCalendar object and sending correctly but i am trying from .net Clinet i am unable to convert that format.every time i sent it takes null value because i am sending datetime format like[03/23/2016 12:00 P.M]  .so i need to pass in datetime like (2016-03-06T14:23:00.000+08) format

Comment: hi , John Ephraim Tugado thanks for reply .. i am not using json to java api .Here i am using SOAP and XML to pass the data to Java webservices.