# what is this 2017-02-06T08:11:24.6728677Z time format? and how can be implemented in jmeter?

Tags: datetime, time, jmeter

what is this time format? - 2017-02-06T08:11:24.6728677Z
How can this be implemented in jmeter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time format in is **timestamp for local timezone**. The **Z** stands for timezone.

In JMeter you need to use

```
${__time(yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssssZ)}
```

in order to receive the timestamp for current timezone

```
2017-02-15T12:20:0053+0200
```

If you want to keep the **Z** in the date use

```
${__time(yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssss)}Z
```

References:

- [Where's the DateTime 'Z' format specifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833102/wheres-the-datetime-z-format-specifier)
- https://hellotestworld.com/2016/02/02/cheatsheet-for-jmeter-__time-function-calls/